# SASS Mixin for all borders?

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm currently working on a site for one of our clients and the design includes a lot of dotted borders. The CSS for these always takes the form of:

```
border-direction: 1px dotted $bdrColor;
```

where direction is top, right, bottom or top. As this border is used so frequently throughout the site I thought it would be cool to create a mixin for this which could be referenced when required with me just passing in the direction I wish the border to go. Something along the lines of:

```
@mixin dotted-border($direction){
border-$direction: 1px dotted $articleSubContentBdrColor; 
}
```

However my concatenation of my $direction variable is incorrect and the SASS doesnt compile. Is this even possible as I have noticed that Compass have SASS mixins for each direction with their border-radius mixins.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Is your mixin really even saving anything?  `$my-border: 1px dotted; .foo { border-left: $my-border red; }`

Comment: It's not the most useful mixin admittedly. But it would mean a single style could be defined for borders on the site and then just the direction is added to the mixin when it needs to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@mixin dotted-border($direction,$articleSubContentBdrColor){
   border-#{$direction}: 1px dotted $articleSubContentBdrColor; 
}
```

Example

```
body{
   @include dotted-border(right, black);
}
```